# Setting onClick event of a generated HTML text field

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, onclick

I am trying to generate HTML code string for a text field. The problem is that I am not able to get the onchange event working in the generated HTML text field.

Script in my HTML page is as follows:

```
function validateSC1(){
  //check something
}

var myStepContent = new StepContent("sc1", "First Name", inputType.Text, true, validateSC1);
document.getElementById("loc").innerHTML = myStepContent.generateCode().getCode();
```

The validateSC1 function is supposed to be onchange event of the text field that is to be generated.

Now the StepContent function is as follows:

```
function StepContent(id, label, type, mandatory, validation){
    this.init = function(){
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
        this.type = type;
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
        this.validation = validation;
        this.output = "";
    }

    this.generateCode = function(){
        if(this.type == inputType.Text){
            this.output += this.label + ": <br><input id='" + this.id + "' type='text' onclick='" + this.validation + "'><br>";
        }
        return this;
    }

    this.getCode = function(){
        return this.output;
    }

    this.init();
}
```

I am not being able to get the onchange even to work. I even changed it to onclick event to see if it works. Can anyone please advice or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Note: I want to assign the onchange event before the generated HTML code is rendered onto the page, so I cannot use the addEventListener to the generated text field.

Comment: `onclick='" + this.validation + "'`

When you are doing that, you are taking a method and turning it into a string. It is NOT going to reference the method reference you passed in. Plus you are setting innerText, not sure how that is rendering HTML.

Comment: Oh I removed that line of code since it was just a trial statement I tried on. Did not mean to put it there. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery use `$(document).on` syntax on dynamically loaded html

for change use

```
$(document).on('change', '#element_id', function() {
    //your code
});
```

The same will work with any type of event and can be assigned before the content even exists since it will check the DOM for matching elements each time the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have parens for your onclick event.
You also use single and double quotes backwards from what I think convention is.
I would check your object in Firebug.